# GDI Objects - Error creating windows handle

Tags: c#, object, window, gdi, handle

I have been struggling to diagnose a problem all day relating to "Error creating windows handle". The main cause of this issue seems to be running out of GDI objects which would seem logical as I've found the place it could be happening.

The analysis tools I've used (Bear, GDIView - http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/gdi_handles.html)  list all the GDI objects used by a process and have two columns, "GDI Total" and "All GDI". The column which is increasing is "All GDI" but you cannot see details relating to this in the preview pane below. What are these GDI objects? and how do they differ from the ones been generated in the GDI Total column? Is there anyway I can check these objects to see which are been created?

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: This error comes from something (simple) wrong in your code, you don't need to care much about the internals, just scan your code and check it, I've experienced this exception but it can be caused by many reasons, almost the reasons are simple but we couldn't think of.

Comment: No, this happens when a program has consumed its quota of USER Objects.  Windows.  Easy to do in a Winforms app by using Controls.Clear() or Remove() without also disposing the removed controls.  And easy to see in Taskmgr.exe